# Script writing to get Distinct value from Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I want to create a custom distinct function where I can write simple distinctBy script of multiple field names to be distinct together. So is there anyway in ElasticSearch to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did, is made use of [Terms Aggregation using Script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) to *construct keys from three different fields* and then apply [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on this *concatenated* field to give what you want.

I've created a sample index with 3 fields, (`field1`, `field2` and `field3` of type `keyword`) with documents as below. You can check the query and the results part to see how they appear. Key point is the `keys` in the result part are distinct.

### Sample Documents

```
POST myfieldindex/mydocs/1
{
  "field1": "Football",
  "field2": "Premier League",
  "field3": "Chelsea"
}

POST myfieldindex/mydocs/3
{
  "field1": "Football",
  "field2": "Premier League",
  "field3": "Liverpool"
}

POST myfieldindex/mydocs/3
{
  "field1": "Football",
  "field2": "Premier League",
  "field3": "ManCity"
}
```

### Query

```
POST myfieldindex/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "myagg":{  
         "terms":{  
            "script":{  
               "source":"doc['field1'].value + params.param + doc['field2'].value + params.param + doc['field3'].value",
               "lang":"painless",
               "params":{  
                  "param":","
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Query Results

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "myagg": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Football,Premier League,Chelsea",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Football,Premier League,Liverpool",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Football,Premier League,ManCity",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So you can see in the results as how `key` are constructed (keys are unique).

Let me know if this helps!